# Only while running on VS 2010: COMException: Catastrophic Failure: Error Code: -2147418113

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am stuck with this error: while trying to use an old DLL in .Net Framework 4.0 
If I change project target type to 3.5 then no error appears.
The strange is that all this happen Only while running inside VS 2010. If I run the executable from Windows Explorer, no problem occurs in 3.5 and 4.0.
Seems like some bug in vshost? VS 2010 Express, or .net framework?

**UPDATE: This BUG only happen on WPF Standalone Application, if a change it to XBAP WPF I can use the dll without bigger problems, only a message telling it could no stop debugging.**

I will leave this question open here, waiting to see if there is some progress on the connect.microsoft.com about this ticket.

**Is there some way to make my .net4 app.config  load this specific dll(CobreBemX.dll) using the .net 3.5 ?**

I think this is some bug then i submitted it to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636697/comexception-was-unhandled-catastrophic-failure

Here is the code where it throws that COMException:

```
//Cria instância do objeto CobreBemX
CobreBemX.ContaCorrente _CobreBemX = new CobreBemX.ContaCorrenteClass();
//Monta arquivo de licença de teste para banco 001 carteira 18
_CobreBemX.ArquivoLicenca = @"C:\CobreBemX\Exemplos\Licencas\237-09.conf"; // THIS LINES CAUSES THE PROBLEM ON .NET 4.0    IF I CHANGE TARGET FRAMEWORK TO 3.5  NO PROBLEM HAPPENS
```

This is the stack trace:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message=Falha catastrófica
  Source=CobreBemX.ContaCorrente
  ErrorCode=-2147418113
  StackTrace:
       at CobreBemX.ContaCorrenteClass.set_ArquivoLicenca(String Value)
       at EmissorBoletosWindows.MainWindow.button1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CRM\Cobranca\EmissorBoletosWindows\EmissorBoletosWindows\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 90
       at EmissorBoletosWindows.MainWindow.Window_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CRM\Cobranca\EmissorBoletosWindows\EmissorBoletosWindows\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 39
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
       at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
       at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
       at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at EmissorBoletosWindows.App.Main() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CRM\Cobranca\EmissorBoletosWindows\EmissorBoletosWindows\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can we get a little more information? Like maybe the code surrounding the line that throws the exception, and/or a stack trace? What is this "old DLL"? Is it a COM component? What language was it written in? Do you have the source code?

Comment: The old DLL is third part, I don´t know what it is written. I think that it is an COM component.

Comment: I noticed also that this only happens while running inside VS 2010. IF i run the .exe outside Visual Studio, no problem occurs, no matter what Target Framework i use (3.5 or 4.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now this has no solution other than use XBAP

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the top of the stack, the method suggests the library is performing some software licensing processing.  My guess (and it *is* a guess) is that the library is using the executable's name and path to locate the license and, because the application is running through VSHost, this is failing causing an error which is expressed as a COM exception.

The fact it works fine outside of VSHost would lend weight to this.  You could use a tool such as [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642) to possibly see where it is tripping up.

Comment: Yes, this line where the DLL loads a software licensing file. What is strange is that the error only occurs inside VS 2010 + .net 4. If i change the target framework or run outside VS 2010, no problem occurs. I tought it could be some permission problem, so i gave Full Trust to Everybody in the folder.

Comment: Before this, I installed FileMon, but there are many entries listed, so I am not seeing cleary what could be the cause for this.

Comment: @Tony, use the FileMon filtering to limit the entries to just your application.